# UITableView contentInset issues after UIkeyboard disappears from last text field

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a table view and once the uikeyboard dismisses the last text field with the return key the table view's contentInsets seem to get all sorts of misplaced.

Here the table view cells align correctly with this piece of code

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetHeight(self.navigationController.toolbar.frame) + 5.0, 0);
```

[image: First cell showing correct alignment]

Then here's the last cell

[image: Last cell showing correct alignment]

Then I tap the last text field in the view and for the cell to align to the top of the keyboard I have to use this code

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

[image: Setting the contentInset to defaults]

Now once I dismiss the keyboard the first cell looks like this

[image: First cell bad alignment]

And the last cell looks like this

[image: Last cell bad alignment]

If I add this code to when the keyboard gets dismissed the first cell looks like the first image which is good but it makes the last cell look even worse as it brings the bottom of the view to half of the fifth cell (there are ten cells altogether). If anyone could help I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height + [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by getting the height of the keyboard and toolbar and updating the contentInset within a custom method I created.

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height, 0.0, keyboardHeight + 5.0, 0.0)];
```

Just in case someone finds this useful I set a notification in the `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(getKeyboardHeight:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then in my `getKeyboardHeight` method

```
keyboardHeight = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
keyboardHeight += self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height;
```